# MySQL: In a single query, how can I check if a specific group of associations exist?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
groupID | username
------------------
1       | joe1
1       | bobby
2       | joe1
3       | joe1
3       | bobby
3       | sally
```

I want to check if there exists a group ID with only `joe1` and `bobby` (in this case it would be `true` because `groupID` `1` has exactly `joe1` and `bobby`).

Comment: Maybe `select count(*) as c, groupid from table where groupid in(select groupid from table where username in ('joe1', 'bobby')) having c = 2 group by groupid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
select exists (
  select groupID
  from tbl
  group by groupID
  having group_concat(username order by username) = 'bobby,joe1'
) as group_exists
```

You need to pass the usernames sorted.

Works when `username` doesn't contain a comma.

Another way:

```
select exists (
  select groupID
  from tbl
  group by groupID
  having sum(username in ('bobby','joe1')) = 2
     and count(*) = 2
) as group_exists
```

But here you need to maintain the count of the input names (`2` in this case).

And here is something fency for MariaDB supporting `VALUES()` in SELECT queries:

```
with input(username) as (
  VALUES ('joe1'), ('bobby')
)
select exists (
  select t.groupID
  from input i
  natural join tbl t
  group by t.groupID
  having count(*) = (select count(*) from input)
     and count(*) = (select count(*) from tbl t1 where t1.groupID = t.groupID)
) as group_exists
```

For MySQL 8 you can use a UNION query as CTE:

```
with input(username) as (
  select 'joe1' union select 'bobby'
)
select exists (
  select t.groupID
  from input i
  natural join tbl t
  group by t.groupID
  having count(*) = (select count(*) from input)
     and count(*) = (select count(*) from tbl t1 where t1.groupID = t.groupID)
) as group_exists
```

Or pass the usernames as JSON array and parse it with JSON_TABLE():

```
with input as (
  select username
  from json_table(
    '["joe1","bobby"]',
    '$[*]' columns (username varchar(100) path '$')
  ) j
)
select exists (
  select t.groupID
  from input i
  natural join tbl t
  group by t.groupID
  having count(*) = (select count(*) from input)
     and count(*) = (select count(*) from tbl t1 where t1.groupID = t.groupID)
) as group_exists
```

Or this one, which might be simpler but slower:

```
select exists (
  select t.groupID
  from (select '["joe1","bobby"]' as input) i
  cross join tbl t
  group by t.groupID, i.input
  having count(*) = json_length(i.input)
     and sum(json_contains(i.input, json_quote(t.username), '$')) = json_length(i.input)
) as group_exists
```

Comment: Here are the first two queries in SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1465/8 I tested all but the MariaDB query and the last one under a couple of conditions and they're good.